# How to use modularized functions inside other modularized functions in C

Tags: c, function, gcc, compiler-errors, modularization

I'm doing a more complex project in c, but this example here is the same for what i need and the names of examples will just changed, but, again, is the same thing from what i am doing.
Let's say I have this file structure:

```
|--project/
|--main.c
|--modules/
|   |--include/
|      |--module1.h
|      |--module2.h
|      |--module3.h
|   |--impl/
|      |--module1.c
|      |--module2.c
|      |--module3.c
```

Module2 uses functions I created and the implementated of my module1. Therefore, there is a dependence of module2 on module1. In other words, my module2 calls module1.

module1.h

```
#ifndef MODUL1_H
#define MODUL1_H

void functionModule1();

#endif
```

module2.h

```
#ifndef MODUL2_H
#define MODUL2_H

void functionModule2();

#endif
```

module3.h

```
#ifndef MODUL3_H
#define MODUL3_H

void functionModule3();

#endif
```

module1.c

```
#include "module1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void functionModule1() {
    (...)
}
```

module2.c

```
#include "module2.h"
#include "module1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void functionModule2() {
    functionModule1();
    (...)
}
```

module3.c

```
#include "module3.h"
#include "module2.h"
#include "module1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void functionModule3() {
    functionModule2();
    (...)
}
```

main.c

```
#include "module3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    functionModule2();
    (...)
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiler the files in this way: `gcc main.c module/impl/* -o a.out`

But i receive an error:

```
fatal error: module1.h: Nonexistent file or directory
    1 | #include "module1.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

fatal error: module2.h: Nonexistent file or directory
    1 | #include "module2.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

fatal error: module3.h: Nonexistent file or directory
    1 | #include "module3.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What am i doing wrong?

I tried what I explained above;

Comment: Add `-Imodules/include` to your compiler flags so it knows where to look for the headers.

Comment: @Shawn `gcc -Imodules/include main.c module/impl/* -o a.out` like this?

Comment: @TomKarzes Is just an example. I believe this does not affect the error. In my project the functions have arguments.

Comment: Suggestion: Sequence the `#include` statements _from general to specific_, not the reverse as you've done. Eg: `<stdio.h>` is _generally_ useful (to many C programs). In the future you may wish to write a macro that, for instance, uses _fundamental_ functions like `printf()`... Start with OS specific headers, if required, then language headers, then finally the application specific headers... As a rule-of-thumb, this practice will help you make progress more quickly.

Comment: Use a decent programming IDE and you won't run into problems like this. Manually appending `-I` etc to the compiler was how we programmed in the stone age (or well, 1990s). Don't waste time on irrelevant crap like setting up paths and creating make files - this is what an IDE exists for. If your IDE still requires you to manually pass along `-I` (like Eclipse) then get a better IDE that is actually useful for programming.

Comment: @Lundin Which IDE you recomend for C?

Comment: Depends on your target and host. Personally, I don't really do any PC programming these days, but more or less exclusively embedded systems.